# Webpage Archivel into mht/mntml

Tags: amazon-s3, mhtml

I want to store  the webpage into mht/mntmt format and  Archive in AWS s3. Kindly help us on how to do it

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Kindly help me if you have archived a entire webpage

Comment: It appears that [What is MHT? What Opens a MHT? File Format List from WhatIs.com](https://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/MHT-MHTML-document-Microsoft) is a way to save a web page. You could then upload that file to S3.  What have you tried? What problems are you experiencing?